Unable to mock final field using mockito-inline dependency
I am writing junit test case for a class which has a final field
public enum TestClass {

INSTANCE;
@Getter private final Employeecaller caller=getEmployeeCaller();

  private EmployeeCaller getEmployeeCaller(){
   //Some implementation
     return new Employeecaller();
   }
}

My test depedencies are
junit5.x
EasyMock 4.x
Junit-4-12-migration 5.x
Mockito-inline 3.x
Mockito-junit-jupiter 3.x

And my test class has
public class TestCaseClass{

    @Test
    public void testInstance(){
    TestClass obj=mock(TestClass.class);
    // testcase code continues
    }
}

when I do TestClass obj=mock(TestClass.class);
I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:cannot subclass final class TestClass
